# Nagios plugins error

Tags: nagios

```
[root@245557-web4 etc]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh --help

Wrong Syntax: check_mem.sh --help

Usage: check_mem.sh [-w|--warning]<percent free> [-c|--critical]<percent free>


[root@245557-web4 etc]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh -w 3 -c 4
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 59: machinfo: command not found
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 1%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 2%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 1%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 2%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 1%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 2%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 1%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 2%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 1%3: integer expression expected
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh: line 119: [: 2%3: integer expression expected
OK - Memory usage: total: MB - used: MB(%) - free: MB(%);Top 5 Memory Processes(memKB,pname,pid):  138062 mysqld 2643, 80454 cvd 3169, 76292 httpd 19706, 76043 httpd 18358, 76043 httpd 16573|Memory usage=MB;;;0;
```

Comment: Check the following [one](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Solaris/check_mem-2Epl/details).

Answer (score 0):

The 'check_mem.sh' script hasn't been maintained very well.  Use 'check_mem.pl', this can be found in the 'contrib' folder in the most recent versions of nagios-plugins.  Available from: http://www.nagios.org/download/plugins